# How to install kali while removing the existing ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kali-linux, system-installation

My question is, currently i have a harddisk of 1 tb in which i have given 40gb space to ubuntu and 410gb for /home and another ext 4 partition of 510gb for my own user data. Now i want is to delete ubuntu and install kali without losing my own user data of 510gb.

Comment: you can do that by installing Kali on a different drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to imply that your disk is partitioned, and that the Ubuntu OS and /home reside on their own partitions. Assuming that this is so:

Take a backup.

Remove the Ubuntu and/or /home partition.

Follow the [installation instructions](https://www.kali.org/docs/installation/hard-disk-install/). At step 9, select *Guided - use the largest continuous free space*.

Other options for creating free space are shrinking the /home and user data partitions, or consolidating and shrinking them.

Comment: thanks a lot berndbausch

Comment: Let me reiterate that you should definitely take a backup of whatever data is important to you. It's easy to push the wrong button and end up destroying your data, and even if you push the right button, there is no guarantee that the installation software leaves your data alone.